# What contributes to differences in click structure for populations of the same species?

Tags: water, marine-mammals, dolphins, echolocation-clicks

I am examining the case of Pacific White-sided Dolphins as an example. Reading Melissa Soldvevilla's 2017 paper sparked my interest in this topic. In the paper, 'Geographic variation in Risso’s dolphin echolocation click spectra', she explores the case of Pacific White-sided dolphins having two different click types but that those click types are not clearly geographically bound. Meaning Pacific white-sided dolphins in the Southern California Bight have been found making both click type A (22 kHz, 27.5 kHz, and 39 kHz) and click type B (22 kHz, 26 kHz, and 37 kHz).

Soldevilla did state that there could be two possible hypotheses:

1. Two morphologically and genetically distinct populations overlap in the Southern California Bight.
   OR (but less likely)
2. That Lags changes click type with prey type.

I wonder why this occurs or if there has been any recent research into a similar case study? Has either hypothesis been proved correct or has another possibility been uncovered? What contributes to differences in click structure for populations of the same species?

Link to 2017 Soldevilla - Geographic variation in Risso’s dolphin echolocation click spectra: https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.4996002

Comment: Can you include a link to Soldvevilla's paper?

Comment: Just added it, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of these hypotheses having been further investigated for Pacific white-sided dolphins yet.  Ideally, a study with passive acoustic monitoring and genetic sampling or passive acoustic monitoring and prey sampling would provide useful information.

Here are two more studies that have more information on Pacific white-sided dolphin clicks than the Risso's paper you cited that may be helpful as you look into the topic more.

Soldevilla et al 2010 Aquatic Biology
https://www.int-res.com/articles/ab2010/9/b009p049.pdf

Henderson and Hildebrand 2011 JASA
https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.3592213